# dashboard index page four errors but localhost is good working

Tags: php

In localhost code is working properly,Mean while in server errors are occurring,errors list mentioned in below  image

[image]

Comment: You have an outdated version of PHP on your machine and a newer one on your server, you should adapt to the newer version and update your code and your local machine

Comment: That is new from PHP 7. The error message is perfectly clear. You can't have a class and a method using the same name.

Comment: That is because your local have old php version while the server have a new one

Comment: And this is where virtualization comes in. Always try to match your local environment as well as you can with your production environment so you don't run into unnecessary errors like these.

Answer (score 2):

That is new from PHP 7. The error message is perfectly clear. You can't have a class and a method using the same name.

See here for more:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php